# Sharepoint 2013 Community site: Get values from "Discussions List" list

Tags: list, development, discussion-board, 2013, community

Im trying to get values from "Discussions List", When I tried to get the values of "Body" field from that list its giving only the values of the replies of discussion. I couldn't access the values of the discussions, and also its giving exceptions when I try to get the custom column values.

```
SPSite oSpSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWeb oSPWeb = oSpSite.OpenWeb();
SPList oSpListPost = oSPWeb.Lists["Discussions List"];
SPListItemCollection oSpListItemClnPost = oSpListPost.Items;

foreach (SPListItem post in oSpListItemClnPost)
{     
    String synopsis = post["Body"].ToString(); 
}
```

This code only giving me the values of the replies of discussions, but I wanted to get the values of the discussions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the view for this, if you look closely with your current code - look at the first post iteration, it starts from ID=2 instead of 1, change the view to enumerate over subject and reply both.

So instead of

```
SPListItemCollection oSpListItemClnPost = oSpListPost.Items;
```

try this

```
SPListItemCollection oSpListItemClnPost = oSpListPost.GetItems(oSpListPost.Views["Flat"]);
```

or any other view suitable to you.

Kindly let me know for any issue.